# Type Assertion error when accessing a list declared inside a struct

Tags: go

I have created a struct that has a list, containing references to values of the same struct type. I am new to the go language and unable to figure out a way to access the values that automatically resolve to the above struct type.Something like this in java:

```
 class Node{
    String value ;
    String key;
    List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    public Node(String key, value) {
       // rest of the code follows
    }  
 }

class AccessNode {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     Node node = new Node("key", "value");
      // The values automatically resolve to type Node.
     for(Node node : node.children) {
       // do something
     }
}
```

The Node is defined as follows:

```
type Node struct {
   key      string
   value    string
   isword   bool
   childern *list.List // This is essentially a list of Node}

// Next two functions are a copy of implementation in list package.

func (n *Node) Init() *Node {
    n.isword = false
    n.childern = list.New()
    return n}

func New() *Node {
    return new(Node).Init()}
```

Now I iterate over the children and return whenever, I get a Node whose value partially matches with the string to be compared against.

```
func countMatchingChars(key string, node *Node) (int, *Node) {
    count := 0
    for e := node.childern.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
            // Getting error when accessing e.Value.key
            if c := MatchCount(e.Value.key, key); c > 0 {
                return c, e.Value
         }
    }}
```

I am getting the following error

```
./trie.go:53: e.Value.key undefined (type interface {} has no field or method key)
./trie.go:54: cannot use e.Value (type interface {}) as type *Node in return argument: need type assertion
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution and along with it have discovered interfaces in go :)

```
if c := MatchCount(e.Value.(*Node).key, key); c > 0 {
        return c, e.Value.(*Node)
    }
```